# SQL to pick the next value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of values. Each value may have 1 or more entry, but only 1 should be active at any one time. The table has a primary INT ID

I need a method to make the 'current' value inactive and make the 'next' value the active value.  If the current active value is the last active, instead make the first value active. Values with only 1 entry will always be active.

The sequence should work like below

[image: Sample Sequence]

Is anyone able to provide a way to achieve this?

Comment: Which database (and version) are you using? Add a tag.

Comment: I think that in the row with ID=1, Value = 'Apple', Fourth Run, you have Active = '1' instead of '0'.  Is it right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think that there is only one column called 'Active', and the table has the only objective to show us how the values "run".

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the `create table` statement for the table in question, some sample data (ideally as  `insert into` statements) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: George Menoutis - MSSQL2016 tag added

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name - No, that is the result of 4 seperate runs, one column for each run to show the sequence

Answer (score 1):

You should not be showing runs in separate columns.  Your data should put this information in separate *rows*.  So your data should have a separate set of rows for each run:

```
id    value    run    active
1     Apple     1       1
2     Apple     1       0
3     Apple     1       0
4     Banana    1       1
5     Banana    1       0
6     Cherry    1       1
1     Apple     2       0
2     Apple     2       1
3     Apple     2       0
4     Banana    2       0
5     Banana    2       1
6     Cherry    2       1
```

You can add the next run as:

```
with r as
      select t.*, max(run) over () as max_run,
             row_number() over (partition by run, value order by id) as seqnum,
             lag(active) over (partition by run, value order by id) as prev_active
      from runs
     ) 
insert into runs (id, value, run, active)
    select id, value, max_run + 1, 
           (case when prev_active = 1 then 1
                 when prev_active is null or seqnum = 1 then 1
                 else 0
            end) as active
    from r
    where run = max_run;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I don't think I was very clear. The table only has 6 rows, and the ID, Value and Active columns.  When the process is run, it should change
Active=0 for id 1 and Active=1 for id 2
Active=0 for id 4 and Active=1 for id 5.  New rows are not added to the table for each run.

Comment: @Rob . . . And my answer is saying that new rows *should* be added to the table.  You should not be storing the runs in separate columns.  I think the answer is clear.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I CAN'T add rows or columns to the table. I don't need to track a history of changes, just update the next value to active.  This is currently being done manually, and I want a way to automate it.  So I'm looking for a way to achieve the above without making changes to the table or adding new rows, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a check, that is select id from the table is not max(id) of that table, then update the log to inactive and then update the id+1 to active.
And if select id from the table is max(ID) then simply update that row to inactive and update min(ID) to active.

build the query, itll be fun.

Comment: I know the logic for what needs doing, but need assistance in creating the actual SQL.